# "Could not load the default credentials" - PubSub Node.js module using the Emulator

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm having an issue with the PubSub module for Node.js. I've created a local environment using Docker and the PubSub emulator. I'm able to publish a message and retrieve it using the asynchronous pull (as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull). However when I'm trying to use the synchronous pull (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous-pull) I keep having the following error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more
>   information. at GoogleAuth.
>   (/var/code/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:167:23)
>   at next (native) at fulfilled
>   (/var/code/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:19:58)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>   (node:493) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was
>   handled asynchronously (rejection id: 32)

This error happens whenever I'm trying to instantiate the v1 PublisherClient or SubscriberClient:

```
const pubsub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

new pubsub.v1.PublisherClient();
new pubsub.v1.SubscriberClient();
```

I feel like the v1 components do not work with the emulator but connect directly to the cloud services instead.
Is there a way to make these clients connect to the emulator rather than the cloud? I can't find any...
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to solve this issue: both PublisherClient and SubscriberClient constructors have options that set the path to the emulator. The options are `servicePath` and `port`. You also need valid credentials to pass to the `sslCreds` option, generated using the `grpc` module. Below is a sample:

```
const grpc = require('grpc');

const subscriber = new pubsub.v1.SubscriberClient({
  servicePath: 'path.to.your.emulator',
  port: 8080, // port your emulator is running on (default is 443)
  sslCreds: grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
});
```

Here is the complete answer: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/346

Answer (score 1):

The following TS sample seems to work for me.

```
import { PubSub, v1 } from "@google-cloud/pubsub";
import * as gax from "google-gax";

if (process.env.PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST) {
    const pieces = process.env.PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST.split(":");

    options = {
        servicePath: pieces[0],
        port: pieces[1],
        isEmulator: true,
        sslCreds: gax.grpc.credentials.createInsecure(),
    };
}
const subClient = new v1.SubscriberClient(options);
```